# Deleted photos are shown in Whatsapp

Tags: windows-10-mobile, whatsapp, photos

Each time I want to attach an image in WhatsApp, I see photos that I took some time ago that were deleted. Its like they are cached on the system. They don't appear in the "Photos App" or "File Explorer". However, they do appear in certain apps like Camera360 or WhatsApp while exploring the gallery from within these apps.

All my apps are updated. I have W10M updated (10586.456 Release Preview), I have cleared all cache in `Storage Configuration`. I have tried connecting the mobile to my PC and I am not able to see these deleted pictures on the PC.

Here is a link where this is discussed:
[Windows Mobile 10 - Did you know your deleted photos dont get deleted?](https://www.reddit.com/r/windowsphone/comments/4gnq65/windows_mobile_10_did_you_know_your_deleted/)

Is there any solution to delete those photos apparently were residual in the system?

Comment: May be these photos are actually really deleted from your phone but uploaded on your OneDrive ? I noticed a few apps that were able to browse my collection (local + OneDrive), may be you've just hit the same "issue". In that case you should try to remove them from your OneDrive and check again if the app sees them.

Comment: @Aureliink Thanks for answer! I have checked OneDrive and is completly empty. The only files I have are OneNote archive and the backup of my phone. :(

Comment: If you try to send one of these deleted pictures on whatsapp, does it actually get sent or do you get an error?

Comment: @slayernoah Whatsapp says missing file. Instead if I use Camera360 (is other app that shows deleted photos) I can edit the photo (add filters, change contrast, color balance...) but when I save the changes, they are not applied. And if I try to delete this photo from Camera360, it disappears but in one second shows again.

Comment: Are the pics stored on an external memory card?

Comment: @slayernoah The pics are in device memory. I suppose that the process of upgrade from Windows Phone 8 to Windows 10 Mobile maybe leave some cache. I guess I will try a factory reset if there's not solution.

Answer (score 2):

There was a bug in the Photos app (I'm not sure if it's been fixed as of this writing) that "deleting" a photo would only remove it from the Photos app but not actually delete it off your phone. You'll need to open File Explorer, select This Device, then Pictures, Camera Roll (or whatever folder the pictures are actually in) and delete them there…

Comment: Doesnt work. In file explorer they are not shown as well... this is kinda annoying and actually a huge bug. Photos must be deleted, not visually but in real..